# Gray highlighted comments with vim in iTerm using Solarized

Tags: vim, themes, iterm

For my vim on my Macbook Pro running in iTerm2 with solarized theme, the background of the comments are highlighted as gray which is very distracting. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own experience is I installed Solarized as a theme using Vundle. By removing the package from Vundle and [installing the theme manually](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#option-1-manual-installation), the comment are not highlighted anymore and the theme works fine.

Alternatively, I tried [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as the package manager and it also works well.

Following is my `.vimrc` configs related with the solarized dark theme.

```
syntax enable
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
set g:solarized_visibility = "high"
let g:solarized_contrast = "high"
colorscheme solarized
```

I'm using Solarized Dark for my iTerm color scheme as well.

The Report Terminal Type is `xterm-256color`. (iTerm2 -> preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Report Terminal Type)